# PHP loop through array then delete the current key

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have the following simple php loop:

```
<?php

$lines = file('test.txt');

foreach($lines as $key => $val) {

  echo $val;
  unset($lines[$key]);
  file_put_contents('test.txt',$lines);

}

?>
```

I could put the `file_put_contents` function after the loop but the problem is that script may fail at any time due to `max execution time` which I can't configure.

The script stops after sometime in the loop so i run the file using cron job and want to loop as many lines as possible and remove the lines looped so that when the cron starts again, it doesn't start from the beginning and repeat the same lines

So how to remove each line in the file immediately after I print its value not after the loop finishes?

Comment: how to remove the current key in the loop after echoing its value?

Comment: if you are going to read the entire file, then does it really matter whether you remove lines after they are being read ?

Comment: @Raiyan yes it matters because the script stops after sometime in the loop so i run the file using cron job and want to loop as many lines as possible and remove the lines looped so that when the cron starts again, it doesn't start from the beginning and repeat the same lines.

Comment: @vascowhite when the file is large, it stops somewhere. The script doesn't just echo the values, it does many things. This is just a demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you want is to echo out each line of test.txt and the write out a test.txt file that contains all the lines that you have not yet echoed. 
The problem seems to be stemming from the fact that you are running up against max execution time limits. 
If you can not change max_execution_time in php.ini, I would advise you to look at [set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) .

If neither is an option, as you can't cleanup before termination due to a exceeding max_execution_time, you'll have to keep writing to the file over and over inside your loop, which isn't pleasant but should continue to work.